# Airflow can not enter the /admin page after initdb

Tags: python, airflow

I wanted to clear all example dags, so that I ran the command `airflow initdb`. However, I was not able to enter the admin page after that, as there was something wrong:

```
  File "/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/menu.py", line 126, in is_accessible
    return self._view.is_accessible()
  File "/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 93, in is_accessible
    (not current_user.is_anonymous and current_user.is_superuser())
  File "/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py", line 114, in is_superuser
    return hasattr(self, 'user') and self.user.is_superuser()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_superuser'
```

I tried to create the same superuser as before, but it still got the same error.

Is there any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by `cleaning the cookie and password stored` in the browser and refresh the admin login page again. It would be showing the login form as normal.

I don't know if this is counted as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Check the indentation in the `create_user` function class under the ModelManager class, it may be the case that the `user` is not returning the data. It would resolve the 'NoneType' object error.